# How i can override an external table in GPFDist

Tags: postgresql, informatica, informatica-powercenter, greenplum, external-tables

I work with Informatica Power Center and GreenPlum - they are interconnected by a connector that works on the basis of gpfdist in the gloader wrapper.
Can I somehow override the place where the external table is created?
Now if I prescribe that the owner name is schema1, then the external table is created in schema1. What do I need to do so that data is read from schema1 but written to schema2 or schema5? And is it possible in principle?

I asked my IPC vendor, and I asked my gp admins, none of them know how to do it. in the informatica pc client in the connector itself, i cannot override the scheme, or I did not find how to do it.

It has been suggested that this can be hardcoded in the gpfdist package and reinstalled, but I have no idea if this is possible, besides, it seems to be written in java, and I don't write in it from the word at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.